# Passing visual range to a :command as its argument

Tags: visual-mode, range, user-commands

I have a command:

```
command! -nargs=1 TmuxSession !tmux.session "<args>"
```

and I want to run it in visual mode so that selected text will be passed as argument.
By selected text I mean selected in visual mode in vim.

How can I achieve that?

I tried running

```
command -nargs=1 -range -register TmuxSession !tmux.session "<args>"
```

but it keeps saying `E471: Argument required`

**Edit:**
I know about using `<C-r>"` to paste an argument and that is how I use the upper command at the moment, but I don't want to copy selection and paste it every time to the command, because this can be done faster using range.

**Edit2:**

Following solution does not work:

```
function! PrintRange() range
    echo getline(a:firstline, a:lastline)
endfunction

command! -range PassRange <line1>,<line2>call PrintRange()
```

because when I want to select second and third word from line containing `one two three` - I get the whole line (obviously).

I need to pass only the selected part of the text.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10573044).

The example given is:

```
 function! PrintGivenRange() range
     echo "firstline ".a:firstline." lastline ".a:lastline
     " Do some more things
 endfunction

 command! -range PassRange <line1>,<line2>call PrintGivenRange()
```

Thus you might want to create a function which would use the range and do the tmux call you want.

In your function, to get the text in the range you can use the `getline()` function which will take `a:firstline` and `a:lastline` as parameters and return the text in the buffer between theses lines. You can have a look at [`:h getline()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getline%28%29) or [`:h getbufline()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getbufline%28%29).

---

**Edit** If you want to get the text characterwise and not linewise you'll have to play with the marks. This edit is inspired from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6271254).

So when you call you command with `:'<,'>PassRange` the marks `'<` and `'>` are set. The doc [`:h '<`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%27%3C) tells us that these marks are used to describe the last visual selection.

Your function would need to look like this:

```
function! PrintGivenRange() range
    " Get the line and column of the visual selection marks
    let [lnum1, col1] = getpos("'<")[1:2]
    let [lnum2, col2] = getpos("'>")[1:2]

    " Get all the lines represented by this range
    let lines = getline(lnum1, lnum2)         

    " The last line might need to be cut if the visual selection didn't end on the last column
    let lines[-1] = lines[-1][: col2 - (&selection == 'inclusive' ? 1 : 2)]
    " The first line might need to be trimmed if the visual selection didn't start on the first column
    let lines[0] = lines[0][col1 - 1:]

    " Get the desired text
    let selectedText = join(lines, "\n")         

    " Do the call to tmux
    execute "!tmux.session " . selectedText 
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've seen this answer and it is not helpful. The return of this echo is giving me line numbers but I need to use the actual selection content.

Comment: @lewiatan in your function you can then use functions like `getline()` or `getbufline()` for example to get the content of your buffer between these lines. See [`:h getline()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getline%28%29) or [`:h getbufline()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getbufline%28%29)

Comment: it is better now, but I still think that's not it. There must be a better way to get the selection.

Comment: @lewiatan Let's way for an answer which better fits your needs then :)

Comment: @lewiatan I think I understand better what you want now. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6271254) one you called your command with the range `'<,'>` you can play with `getpos()` to get the exact position of the mark on the line and thus the code.

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you. So am I getting it right? There is no built-in function for this? Please change the answer and I'll accept it..

Comment: @lewiatan Edited. If a built-in function exists to do that I am not aware of it... Maybe it has already been discussed on the vim-dev mailing list and if it hasn't maybe that would be worth asking.

Answer (score 3):

you can also adapt this one liner

```
command -range TmuxSession execute "!tmux.session " . @*
```

or if you do need multiline visual selection change `@*` to `substitute(@*,"\n"," ","g")`

The `@*` register stores current selection (for linux, on windows there could be different naming convention).

The `-range` is only to avoid an error if you want to execute this command with range marks, i.e. `'<,'>TmuxSession`.

Comment: I did not express myself specific enough. What I meant was the text that is selected in visual mode, but this is also useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can also copy the part you want to use and use `<C-r>"` to paste it.
For example, if you want to run `myCommand` like feh, firefox etc on a the line
`:map mapping Vy:!myCommand <C-r>"<Cr>`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Thanks for trying to help, but I'm not sure this answers OP's question very well.